# Updating the master branch in git

Tags: git

I am new to git and am becoming familiar with the basic commands.

Let's say I cloned a master branch of some project and I made some changes in the branch, and 
I have commited those changes to that branch. How would I update the corresponding master branch using the current branch?

Comment: could you be clearer, by using branch names: if you cloned a master branch then your branch should be named `master`. But what you are looking for is probably `git push` (or more likely `git push origin`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean "How do I update the master branch on the remote git repository?" that is accomplished using [git push](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-push.html).

```
% git push origin master
```

Of course, this assumes your local branch is named "master" as well.

If you mean "How do I update my local master branch with changes I committed on a separate branch in my local repository?" that is accomplished using [git merge](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-merge.html)

```
% git checkout master
% git merge my-other-branch
```

Answer (score 2):

```
git checkout master_branch
git merge fixed_branch
```

Answer (score 0):

1 . You push that local branch to your remote like **git push origin local_branch_name**.
2 . Then merge your pushed branch to your master branch(after checkout to master) like **git merge local_branch_name**

Note: local_branch_name is you created branch like sandbox, etc...